# Why isn't $\forall x \in X, P(x)$ the same thing as a map of types $P:X \to \text{TrueProp}$?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, quantifiers, math-software, type-theory

For example, $\forall x \in X, P(x)$ can be viewed as a map $P : X \to \text{TrueProp}$ the collection of true propositions.

Why do we make the distinction in type theory, which seems to want to reduce all constructions down to a few building blocks?  In type theory $\forall$ is a handled using what's called  a Pi-type, usually, but why didn't they just handle it using a mapping of types?

Certain $\forall$ statements become even more obviously just a map, as in $\forall x \in X, f(x) \in Y$ is the same thing as $f: X \to Y$.

I'm experimenting with software implementations of logic / math, so that's why I've asked this.

Comment: For background: are you familiar with the more standard Curry-Howard correspondence which treats a proposition as being identical to the type of valid proofs of the proposition, and then a $\forall$ universal quantifier becomes a special case of the Pi-type?  (And similarly, an implication proposition $P \rightarrow Q$ has proofs which are functions taking a proof of $P$ as input and returning a proof of $Q$ as output; so it's a special case of a function type, which in turn is a special case of a Pi-type.)

Comment: @DanielSchepler I guess my question is why introduce Pi-types at all, why not use just maps?  This question keeps popping up when you're implementing stuff using an OOP hierarchy.

Comment: Terms of a function type are not themselves types that can have terms. Pi types are types that can have terms.  All a function to Prop gives you is a type family, which is not the same thing as the Pi type of that family.

Comment: @MaliceVidrine why don't we allow function types to have terms?

Comment: Function *types* do have terms. The *terms* of such a type are not generally types, so don't have terms.

Comment: So you're saying the distinction between a Pi-type and map type is that the terms of the first are types, while the terms of the second can be types or non-types?  Then it seems that Pi-type is a specialization of Map type still.

Comment: To see things from my perspective, when you implement code in classes with inheritance you see similarities between two classes and so you try to form a base class which each of the two classes is derived from.  "Derived from" means there is an "is a" relationship usually.  So VectorSpace derived from AbelianGroup, etc.

Comment: I am saying no such thing. If you have $f:A\to Prop$ the language doesn't let you say something like $x:f$, because $f$ is not a Type or (or Proposition or whatever). It's just a term. $\Pi(x:A).B$ is a type, so $a:\Pi(x:A).B$ makes sense in the language; $a$ itself will also not be a type.

Comment: @MaliceVidrine Clearly $a$ takes the place of $f$, so you're saying both $f, a$ are not types.  I'm still not seeing the distinction.  Do you care to make an answer?

Comment: The terms $a$ and $f$ are nothing alike. Writing an answer now...

Comment: @MaliceVidrine, well they're both not types as you said yourself.  So they have that alike.

Comment: In a complete type system any function f has a fixed (exponential) type given its abstraction and application types, but for universal quantified version, all those formulas are not of same type but a family (resemblance) of parameterized product types dependent on the objects denoted by the quantified variable. Curious why simply treating it as category arrows will make your programming easier as compared to a strongly typed programming language? In Haskell function map has type and is a first class citizen...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm going to assume we're talking about a standard type theory, something that's only a minor variation on the lambda cube systems. This said, the two things differ in several important ways.

For one, the $f$ in $f:A\to \mathsf{Prop}$ is not a thing which can have terms of its own; $x:f$ makes no sense in the language. On the other hand, the whole point of $\Pi(x:A).B(x)$ is it's a type which can have terms.

The term $f$ also does something entirely different from a term $g:\Pi(x:A).B(x)$. If $a:A$, then $f(a)$ is a term of type $\mathsf{Prop}$. On the other hand, $g(a)$ is a term of type $B(a)$, not $\mathsf{Prop}$. This is really the central purpose of Pi-types. There are no inference rules that let you take $f$ and generate *a term of type $f(a)$* when given an $a:A$. Certainly, if we have a proof of $\forall (x:A).B(x)$, we should expect to be able to derive a proof of each instance $B(a)$, and this is something you can't do with just a map $B:A\to\mathsf{Prop}$.

Comment: If you have a proof of $\forall (x:A).B(x)$ then you have shown that $B : A \to$ universe $U$, given a definition of $B$, is indeed a map from $A$ into types, each of which we naturally denote by $B(a), a \in A$.  If you have a proof that $B: A \to U$ is a map from $A$ into types, then you can write $\forall (x:A).B(x):U$.  So I'm still not seeing the distinction.  Why can't we do with a map what we can do with a Pi-type?  The argument you gave is not convincing me that Pi-type is not just a special case of the Map type.

Comment: Also, I'm saying $A \to \textbf{Prop}$ is the type, not $f$.  You keep saying that I'm saying $f$ needs to be a type.  I'm saying $f$ is a variable and $f: A \to \textbf{Prop}$ is a declaration of the variables type.   Also there can indeed be maps that are sets - see category theory where a map can be anything not simply a function on sets.

Comment: Yes, $B:A\to U$ is a map into types. But you do not get from $B$ and $a:A$ a term of type $B(a)$. A term $g:\forall(x:A).B(x)$ is *not* a map into types. I don't know how to be clearer that the two do patently different things.

Comment: If you would like to argue that $B:A\to Prop$ and $a:A$ can be used to somehow give you a term $t:B(a)$, I invite you to tell me what rules of inference you think will give you this.

Comment: can the rules of inference in the two perspectives be so different - in fact they are essentially the same thing.  You say "is not a map" into types as if that's a proof in and of itself.  I'm still not seeing what you meant.

Comment: Yes! The inference rules can be so different! Every term of one kind does something different from every term of the other! From here on out I have to assume that you either don't know enough about the subject to be having this conversation, or you're not actually engaging in good faith. Either way, I don't see the purpose in continuing this.

Comment: They are essentially the same rules of inference because I contend that Pi-types are just maps!

Comment: So bad faith. Got it.

Comment: You gave an answer full of statements and no proof.